# Get 1 row of data per day for a given user in PrestoDB

Tags: sql, presto, trino

We have a very large number of rows (10's of millions) for a specific customer and I just want to pull 1 row of data for a specific user of the customer per day for a whole month. Here is a sample of the query for a single day.

```sql
select update_date, name, city
from mydb.mytable
WHERE year = '2021' and month = '05' and dd = '01'
  and customer_id = 'acme' and user_id = 'user123' 
limit 1
```

How do I do this for each day of a month so that I get only 1 row per day for that one customer/user in the most efficient (fastest) manner using PrestDB?

EDIT: I should add that if there is at least 1 row, the single day query returns rather quickly, but if there are no rows for that customer/user for a given day, then it has to look through all the rows to get nothing and that is what takes a long time. I don't think anything but indexing would help solve this, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select update_date, name, city
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id, year, month, day order by update_date desc) as seqnum
      from mydb.mytable t
      where year = '2021' and month = '05' and
            user_id = 'user123' and customer_id = 'acme'
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: We did experiment with `row_number` using a `WITH` query but no luck. We'll give your query a go and see how if it improves the performance.

Comment: shouldn't there be a `WHERE` after `from mydb.mytable t` and before `year =...`

Comment: also, does the `order by update_date desc` provide any performance gains?

Comment: @CraigConover . . . No performance gains.  It just gets the last update of the day.